Prove this sequence is unbounded
I'm teaching myself real analysis, and part of a problem asks me to prove that the sequence $a_n=r^n$ is unbounded for $r>1$. I know I should be able to show it in one of the following ways:

Show that $(a_n)$ does not converge to $a$ for any $a$
Show that for any $M>0$ I can find an $a_k$ st $a_k>M$

But I can't write it up formally when I try either of these methods.
For example, when I try the second method, I don't know what to do with $r^k>M$ since we have not defined or even introduced logarithms yet, so I am unsure if I can use them.
Conceptually, it's so easy to think about, but I am putting it into actual proof. It is frustrating
Thanks for the help!

Actually, the first method straight up is not true. The sequence alternating between $0$ and $1$ does not converge to anything but is bounded. It is true that every bounded sequence has limit-points (a consequence of compactness, you will probably learn about that later), but that is not a common property to use to prove unboundedness with.

Without spelling out how to do it: I think the easiest method is deriving a contradiction by letting $M$ be the smallest natural number bigger than $r^n$ for all $n$ (thus, crutially, the sequence reaches $M-1$ at least). You should be able to do the rest from here, but I'm willing to help if you need more hints :)

@kabelabel I see what you're saying, but if I prove that the series does not converge to any a and is monotone increasing, wouldn't that mean it must diverge to infinity and is therefore unbounded by the monotone convergence theorem?

Ah, you're correct, if you're using the monomonicity of the sequence your first method would theoretically work. Still, I don't think it is necessary, as I alluded to in my second comment :)

@kabelabel I'm not sure if this is the right direction, but from $r^n \geq M-1$ I got to $r^{n-1} \geq M-1$ and so I guess by induction I could get to $r>M-1$? But I'm not sure how this helps.... may I have another hint please haha

Definitely wrong direction, dividing down by $r$ makes things lower. You actually need to increase $n$ until you get above $M$, getting a contradiction.

The best way to do this is to use the minimality of the supremum. Suppose that $\{r^n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ is bounded, then this necessarily means that $M = \sup\{r^n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ exists. Now, it must be the case that the sequence takes on a value in the interval $(\frac{M}{r}, M]$ because otherwise, $\frac{M}{r}$ would actually be a smaller upper-bound for our sequence, contradicting the minimality of $M$. So, take this element of the sequence, say $r^k \in (\frac{M}{r}, M]$ and note that, of course, $r^{k + 1}$ must also be an element of the sequence. However, $$ r^{k + 1} = r\cdot r^{k} > r\cdot \frac{M}{r} = M $$ which is a contradiction. Hence, $M$ cannot exist and so the sequence is unbounded.
Edit: I've implicitly used the fact that $r>1$ in the above reasoning. Where?

Thanks a lot! So, just to be clear, the contradiction is that $r^{k+1}=M$ implies $r^{k+2}>M$ right? Since the supremum can be equal to the largest element of a set?

@Sachin No problem. This argument directly shows that $r^{k + 1} > M$ (observe the sneaky `$>$' sign in the last line of my working out). So, you don't need to say anything about $r^{k + 2}$ --- but you can if you want to.

The supremum can be the largest element of the set but it needn't be and frequently isn't.  Her all we know is that an $r^k$ exists where $\frac Mr < r^k$ and by definition of $M$ that $r^k \le M$.  As that is all we know, we know $r\cdot \frac Mr < r\cdot r^k$ (and $r\cdot r^k \le r\cdot M$ but we don't actually care about that). So $M < r^{k+1}$.  And or contradiction specifically is that $r^{k+1}$ is in our set but $r^{k+1} > \sup$ of our set.

The proof can be done directly/not by contradiction by considering any positive $M$ and the interval $(\frac Mr, M]$.  If there is any $r^k$ so that $\frac Mr < M$ then $r^{k+1}>M$ and $M$ is not an upper bound.  If there is no $r^k$ in $(\frac Mr, M]$ then $M$ is not a least upper bound.  So no $M$ can actually be a least upper bound.  But reals have the upper bound property.  So no least upper bound implies unbounded. (Hmmm, maybe that theoretically still is a proof by contradiction....)

Based on the comment of the original poster, following my answer, I have added an Addendum, which provides an alternative approach.

Since $~r~$ is some fixed number $~> 1,~$ then $~\log(r)~$ is some fixed positive number.  Then, it is sufficient to show that $~\displaystyle n \log(r) = \log\left[ ~r^n ~\right]~$ is unbounded.  That is, if $~\displaystyle \log\left[ ~r^n ~\right]~$ is unbounded, then so is
$$e^{\log\left[ ~r^n ~\right]} = r^n.$$
Another way of saying the same thing is that if $~x~$ is unbounded, then so is $~e^x,~$ because:

$~e^1 > 1.~$

For $~x > 1, ~\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \left[ ~e^x - x ~\right] = e^x - 1 > 0.$


Therefore, the function $~f(x) = e^x - x~$ is always increasing, and $~f(1) > 0.$

So, the problem reduces to showing that $~n \log(r)~$ grows unbounded, with $~r~$ fixed, and $~n~$ going to $~\infty.$
For any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ choose $~N \in \Bbb{Z^+}~$ such that $~\displaystyle N > \frac{\epsilon}{\log(r)} \implies ~N\log(r) > \epsilon.$
Then, for any $~n > N,~$ you have that
$$n\log(r) > N\log(r) > \epsilon.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
Alternative approach that does not use logarithms or the exponential function.
Since $~r > 1, ~$ there exists $~k > 0~$ such that $~r = (1 + k).~$
Note that for any $~m > 0,~$ you have that
$$(1 + m)^2 = 1 + 2m + m^2 > 1 + 2m.$$
Therefore, you have that

$(1 + k)^2 > 1 + 2k.$

$(1 + k)^4 > (1 + 2k)^2 > 1 + 4k.$

$(1 + k)^8 > (1 + 4k)^2 > 1 + 8k.$


Then, you can see that if
$$(1 + k)^{(2^r)} > 1 + [ ~(2^r \times k) ~],$$
then
$$(1 + k)^{[2^{(r+1)}]} > 1 + [ ~2^{(r+1)} \times k ~].$$
So, by induction, for any $~R \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ you have that
$$(1 + k)^{(2^R)} > 1 + [ ~2^R \times k ~].$$
Clearly, the sequence $~2^1 = 2, ~2^2 = 4, ~2^3 = 8, \cdots, ~$ grows unbounded.
So, for any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ choose $~R \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that $~\displaystyle 2^R > \frac{\epsilon}{k}.$
Then,
$$(1 + k)^{(2^R)} > 1 + [ ~2^R \times k ~] > \epsilon.$$
Further, for any $~n > 2^R,~$ you have that
$$(1 + k)^n > (1 + k)^{(2^R)} > \epsilon.$$

Thanks for the solution! My textbook hasn't yet defined logarithms or exponential functions, so I don't know if I can use them. Is there a way to prove this without that?

@Sachin See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.
